# tell org to treat block quotes as a special environment?

Tags: org-mode, quote

In org-mode I use [block quotes](http://orgmode.org/manual/Paragraphs.html).

```
#+BEGIN_QUOTE
Foo.
#+END_QUOTE
```

However, when I do `org-edit-special` inside a block quote, I get `No special environment to edit here`. How can I direct org-mode to treat block quotes (and verse quotes etc) as special environments, so that when I do `C-c '` I can edit the quotation in its own buffer the same way I can with other code blocks?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want this behavior? Do you want to use editing commands specific to a certain mode in this block, or do you just want to see it in an isolated buffer?

Comment: I want the block quote in its own buffer so I can use commands like `beginning-of-buffer`, `end-of-buffer`, and `mark-whole-buffer`.

Comment: There isn't any way to change the behavior of org-edit-special.  If you just want to treat the block as a buffer, select it and narrow the region with `C-x n n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading the comments, it appears you're really looking for this:

- `org-narrow-to-block` to narrow the buffer to the current block

  1. Place cursor within the boundary of a block, e.g. quote block

     ```
     #+BEGIN_VERSE
     Verse Block
     #+END_VERSE

     #+BEGIN_VERBATIM
     Verbatim Block
     #+END_VERBATIM

     #+BEGIN_QUOTE
     Quote Block
     #+END_QUOTE
     ```
  2. Type <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd>

     The buffer will narrow to just the quote block.

     ```
     #+BEGIN_QUOTE
     Quote Block
     #+END_QUOTE
     ```

     > **Note:** If you want your buffer to look more like `org-edit-special`,
     >   then type <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> instead.
     >
     > The buffer will look similar to the example below:
     >
     > ```
     >  Quote Block
     > ```
- `widen` to remove narrowing from current buffer

  1. Type <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd>

     ```
     #+BEGIN_VERSE
     Verse Block
     #+END_VERSE

     #+BEGIN_VERBATIM
     Verbatim Block
     #+END_VERBATIM

     #+BEGIN_QUOTE
     Quote Block
     #+END_QUOTE
     ```

---

This was answer was tested using

> GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.14.13)
>   org-mode version: 9.0

Comment: The shortcut should be C-x n b.

Comment: @user2699  Thanks for catching typo! I'll fix it!

Comment: Yes that's it! Is there a way to define a function like `org-edit-special-or-narrrow-to-block` that would detect which is appropriate and do one or the other? That way I could use the same key binding for both since in my mind it's the same operation, even if not in the mind of Emacs.

Comment: @incandescentman - I believe so but I don't have the elisp skills to do it yet. I imagine the implementation could be similar to `org-metaup`, `org-metadown` or `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c`.

Answer (score -3):

Use instead:

```
#+begin_example
  Foo.
#+end_example
```

Then you would be able to do `org-edit-special` inside the block.